# Solaris ethernet ports: e1000g1 and e1000g2 are not working

Tags: solaris, ethernet, port, devices

I can `plumb` and configure `e1000g0` and `e1000g3` using `ifconfig`, but I can't seem to make use of `e1000g1` or `e1000g2`.

When I try `ifconfig e1000g1 plumb`, I get `ifconfig: plumb: e1000g1: Invalid argument`.

They are part of a single set of four ethernet ports physically included in the system, but for some reason. They exist in `/dev` in the same layout as found on another X4100 that works fine. Even pointing to the same places in `/devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@1/pci1022,7450@1`. However, on this X4100 in question, the items for 1 and 2 do not exist. That is probably where the problem is.

How can I get access to interfaces 1 and 2, and get them to show up in `/devices` so I can access them?

Here is the output of `prtconf -D`:

```
System Configuration:  Sun Microsystems  i86pc
Memory size: 1024 Megabytes
System Peripherals (Software Nodes):

i86pc (driver name: rootnex)
    scsi_vhci, instance #0 (driver name: scsi_vhci)
    isa, instance #0 (driver name: isa)
        i8042, instance #0 (driver name: i8042)
            keyboard, instance #0 (driver name: kb8042)
        asy, instance #0 (driver name: asy)
        motherboard
    pci, instance #0 (driver name: pci)
        pci1022,7450, instance #0 (driver name: pci_pci)
            pci8086,1011, instance #0 (driver name: e1000g)
            pci8086,1011, instance #1 (driver name: e1000g)
            pci8086,1011 (driver name: e1000g)
            pci8086,1011, instance #3 (driver name: e1000g)
        pci1022,7451
        pci1022,7450, instance #1 (driver name: pci_pci)
            pci1000,3060, instance #0 (driver name: mpt)
                sd, instance #2 (driver name: sd)
                sd, instance #4 (driver name: sd)
                sd, instance #5 (driver name: sd)
        pci1022,7451
        pci1022,7460, instance #2 (driver name: pci_pci)
            pci1022,7464, instance #0 (driver name: ohci)
                device, instance #0 (driver name: usb_mid)
                    keyboard, instance #2 (driver name: hid)
                    mouse, instance #3 (driver name: hid)
            pci1022,7464, instance #1 (driver name: ohci)
                storage, instance #0 (driver name: scsa2usb)
                    disk, instance #0 (driver name: sd)
                storage, instance #1 (driver name: scsa2usb)
                    disk, instance #1 (driver name: sd)
            display, instance #0 (driver name: vgatext)
        pci1022,7468
        pci-ide, instance #0 (driver name: pci-ide)
            ide (driver name: ata)
            ide (driver name: ata)
        pci1022,746a
        pci1022,746b
        pci1022,1100
        pci1022,1101, instance #0 (driver name: mc-amd)
        pci1022,1102, instance #1 (driver name: mc-amd)
        pci1022,1103
    pci, instance #1 (driver name: pci)
        pci1022,7450, instance #3 (driver name: pci_pci)
        pci1022,7451
        pci1022,7450, instance #4 (driver name: pci_pci)
        pci1022,7451
    iscsi, instance #0 (driver name: iscsi)
    pseudo, instance #0 (driver name: pseudo)
    options, instance #0 (driver name: options)
    xsvc, instance #0 (driver name: xsvc)
    objmgr, instance #0 (driver name: objmgr)
    used-resources
    cpus
        cpu, instance #0
```

Additional outputs requested by [James](https://serverfault.com/users/90132/james-ogorman) (IP, netmask, broadcast, ether masked using the letter `x`)

```
# ifconfig -a
lo0: flags=2001000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4,VIRTUAL> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000 
e1000g0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet x.x.x.x netmask xxxxxxxx broadcast x.x.x.x
        ether x:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
e1000g3: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 3
        inet x.x.x.x netmask xxxxxxxx broadcast x.x.x.x
        ether x:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
# dladm show-dev
e1000g0         link: up        speed: 100   Mbps       duplex: full
# grep e1000g /etc/path_to_inst
"/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@1/pci8086,1011@1" 0 "e1000g"
"/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@1/pci8086,1011@1,1" 1 "e1000g"
"/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@1/pci8086,1011@2" 2 "e1000g"
"/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@1/pci8086,1011@2,1" 3 "e1000g"
#
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ifconfig -a`, `dladm show-dev` and `grep e1000g /etc/path_to_inst` to your question, please?

Comment: Here you go!....

Comment: do you know that these devices physically exist on the server ?

Comment: @Iain, Yes. They are all four together, just like the rest of our X4100s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is something a little odd going on with your system.

The `dladm` output is only showing e1000g0. It should show all four interfaces even if they're not plumbed. More worrying is that it isn't showing your e1000g3 interface which *is* plumbed.

Here's equivalent output from a T5120 (uses e1000g also), with interfaces e1000g0 and e1000g1 plumbed and configured with IP addresses, the other two interfaces are not plumbed and not connected:

```
# dladm show-dev
e1000g0         link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
e1000g1         link: up        speed: 1000  Mbps       duplex: full
e1000g2         link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: half
e1000g3         link: unknown   speed: 0     Mbps       duplex: half

# grep e1000g /etc/path_to_inst
"/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@2/network@0" 0 "e1000g"
"/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@2/network@0,1" 1 "e1000g"
"/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@3/network@0" 2 "e1000g"
"/pci@0/pci@0/pci@1/pci@0/pci@3/network@0,1" 3 "e1000g"

# ls -l /devices/pci\@0/pci\@0/pci\@1/pci\@0/pci\@2/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Jan 20  2009 network@0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Jan 20  2009 network@0,1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      83,  2 Mar  4  2011 network@0,1:e1000g1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      83,  1 Mar  4  2011 network@0:e1000g0
# ls -l /devices/pci\@0/pci\@0/pci\@1/pci\@0/pci\@3/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Jan 20  2009 network@0
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Jan 20  2009 network@0,1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      83,  4 Mar  4  2011 network@0,1:e1000g3
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     root      83,  3 Mar  4  2011 network@0:e1000g2
```

I'd recommend as a first course of action that you schedule some downtime for this box and perform a reconfiguration reboot. That is, one of:

```
# touch /reconfigure
# init 6
```

**OR**

```
# init 0
grub> boot -r
```

(I can't quite remember how you edit the GRUB options on an X-series box as I don't have any to hand. I think you hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> at the GRUB menu and add the `-r` to the boot arguments.)

Once the box is back up, check `dladm show-dev` again.

Comment: A reconfiguration reboot was successful.